# What statistical method should I use to quantify a tests ability to separate by category?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, anova, variance, manova

Say I have the table of results below. In Test 1 categories a, b, and c produce results which are clearly distinct. In Test 2 the categories produce some separation, though not entirely. Test 3 produces no apparent variation by category.

I would like to know what method should I use to rank/quantify these tests ability to separate out values by category. In the example the different tests produce a single number. The categories a, b, and, c are based on visual assessment and so cannot be described by numerical values.

I have been trying to read up on ANOVA and MANOVA but am still struggling to understand which is applicable to this case, if either?

```
    Test 1  Test 2  Test 3
a   1.55    1.88    0.10
a   2.39    1.55    0.04
a   2.27    2.06    0.37
a   1.61    1.64    0.44

b   0.07    1.93    0.38
b   0.72    1.31    0.15
b   0.37    1.47    0.24
b   0.65    2.80    0.10

c   4.98    3.37    0.22
c   4.63    3.66    0.25
c   4.15    3.17    0.29
c   4.75    2.13    0.33
```

Comment: You could do three separate ANOVA's for each test.

Comment: Aren't the the result from an ANOVA going to vary a lot with the means of the test results? How would I compare the ANOVA results?

Comment: What exactly do you want to test? Do you have the true value for each group a, b, c,...?